# The remote server machine does not exist or is unavaliable (error # 462)

Tags: vba, ms-access, automation, outlook, ms-access-2007

So I have this code in Mcirosoft Outlook. The code runs when new mail comes in, and depending on the sender's name and the attachments, it saves the text files and imports the data into 2 access databases and and runs certain queries pre built in the database. The code errors out when 2 emails which are from the right sender and has the right attachments comes in. The code processes the first email correctly however when the second email is getting processed, the code errors out at the bolded line below.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As MailItem
Dim atmt As Attachment
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim fs As TextStream
Dim dt, invfn, misfn, invdr, misdr, dbfn As String
Dim invt, mist As Boolean
Dim db As Object

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

If inbox.UnReadItemCount = 0 Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    For Each Item In inbox.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
        If Item.SenderName = "Menon, Jayesh" Then
            dt = Left(Right(Item.Subject, 12), 10)
            For Each atmt In Item.Attachments
                If atmt.FileName = "InvalidLoans.txt" Then
                    invfn = "ERLMF_InvalidLoans_" & dt & ".txt"
                    invdr = "C:\Documents and Settings\U299482\Desktop\Data Drop\" & _
                    invfn
                    atmt.SaveAsFile invdr                    
                    Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(invdr)
                    If fs.Read(23) = "Invalid Loans Count = 0" Then
                        invt = False
                        Else
                        invt = True
                    End If
                    fs.Close
                End If
                If atmt.FileName = "MissingLoans.txt" Then
                    misfn = "ERLMF_MissingLoans_" & dt & ".txt"
                    misdr = "C:\Documents and Settings\U299482\Desktop\Data Drop\" & _
                    misfn
                    atmt.SaveAsFile misdr
                    Set fs = fso.OpenTextFile(misdr)
                    If fs.Read(23) = "Missing Loans Count = 0" Then
                        mist = False
                        Else
                        mist = True
                    End If
                    fs.Close
                End If
            Next
            If invt = True Or mist = True Then
                Set db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
                dbfn = "C:\Documents and Settings\U299482\Desktop\Databases\BPDashboard.accdb"
                With db
                    .OpenCurrentDatabase dbfn, True
                    .Visible = True
                    If invt = True Then
                        .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Lns_Spec", "Invalid_Lns", invdr, True
                    End If
                    If mist = True Then
                        .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Lns_Spec", "Missing_Lns", misdr, True
                    End If
                    .Quit
                End With
                Set db = Nothing
            End If
            If invt = True Then
                Set db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
                dbfn = "C:\Documents and Settings\U299482\Desktop\Databases\CORE IDP.accdb"
                With db
                    .OpenCurrentDatabase dbfn, True
                    .Visible = True
                    **CurrentDb.Execute "A0_Empty_ERLMF_InvalidLoans_2013-04-02", dbFailOnError**
                    .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Lns_Spec", "ERLMF_InvalidLoans_2013-04-02", invdr, True
                    CurrentDb.Execute "AppendERLMF", dbFailOnError
                    CurrentDb.Execute "FaxRF Crystal Append", dbFailOnError
                    .Quit
                End With
                Set db = Nothing
            End If
            Item.UnRead = False
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting over-lapping `.Execute` commands. You need to ensure that the first execution finishes before starting the next. To fix, I'd start by declaring a Public variable `Executing` then move the below code into its own method.

```
Sub Execute()

  Executing = True

  Set db = CreateObject("Access.Application")
  dbfn = "C:\Documents and Settings\U299482\Desktop\Databases\CORE IDP.accdb"
  With db
    .OpenCurrentDatabase dbfn, True
    .Visible = True
    CurrentDb.Execute "A0_Empty_ERLMF_InvalidLoans_2013-04-02", dbFailOnError
    .DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "Lns_Spec", "ERLMF_InvalidLoans_2013-04-02", invdr, True
    CurrentDb.Execute "AppendERLMF", dbFailOnError
    CurrentDb.Execute "FaxRF Crystal Append", dbFailOnError
    .Quit
  End With
  Set db = Nothing

  Executing = False

End Sub
```

Then, when calling the function, surround it with a loop that tests to see if `Executing` is false.

```
Do
  If Executing = False Then
    Execute
    Exit Do
  End If
Loop
```

Comment: are you sure? because the code errors out at CurrentDB.Execute. which occurs only after the db got closed during the 1st email.

Comment: You may be right. Does `CurrentDb.Execute` run synchronously? What happens when you step through the code? Are you able to move to the next statement immediately?